# How to specify a class name for a generated Datatable

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using [Chumper's Datatable package for Laravel](https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable), and want to add a class name to the generated table. I tried passing it via `setOptions()`:

```
$table = Datatable::table()
    ->addColumn($columns)
    ->setUrl(route('admin.reports.top_recruiters.datatable'))
    ->setOptions(array(
        'bProcessing' => true,
        'class' = 'table-striped'
    ))
    ->noScript();

echo $table->render();
```

However, that method appears to only pass options that are specific to the Datatables JavaScript.

The [documentation](https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable#table) does not appear to mention the way. What is the right way to apply custom classes to the generated table?

Answer (score 0):

A little source diving revealed an undocumented method in the `Table` class called `setClass()`.

```
public function setClass($class)
{
    $this->className = $class;
    return $this;
}
```

The class name can be applied to the table instance like this:

```
$table = Datatable::table()
    ->setClass('<your class name>')
```